Unity 3d weird stretching on collisions
When i collide with a game object (obstacle) with my player, it causes weird stretching and scale changes.

Here my obstacle collides with the side railing

here my obstacle collides with the player (me) (getting launched up is intentional.
I thought this was an issue caused by baking (i baked for occlusion) as it wwas cuased instantly after i baked (i think). So i cleared baked data it didnot work.

sounds like you have code to make that happen........

no this isnt done through code, any ideas?

colliders dont randomly change..

I was using a similar setup like with platforms and walls and as it turned out for me, the issue was to have the child objects and platforms have distinct colliders. Hope it helps!
